# WCF: For a stateless service, can perSession be better over perCall

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WcfService with seven contracts.

Will it be better to prefer **PerSession** over **PerCall** as PerSession will be creating only one service instance and that can be further used for seven requests, while, PerCall will be creating service instances, everytime, I call one of those contracts.

I mean which way is more optimized and faster.

Comment: I can't tell from the data you've provided.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, you should use single instance context mode.